# Form values kept as cookies after submit & page change

Tags: javascript, html, forms, cookies

I am currently writing a HTML page with some javascript controlling various events.

When the user clicks submit, the page automatically loads the response form the server (this is a test page used to show the XML sent to the server and the resulting response). I want the user to be able to switch back to the form and see the values that they have selected (3x dropdowns - one controlled by the selection of another, 3x textboxes - values controlled by the dropdowns, and a text area which is loaded from a text file the user has selected using input type="file" ).

This page is only useful if the user can switch back to the form and then back to the response easily. I have attempted to use cookies to save the values and then load them into the inputs when  the user returns to the page, but my code is refusing to work.

I have tried a few different examples on the internet, as well as using Garlic.js but no matter what I try, when i click "back" in the browser and the form loads, all my input is gone. I have tested the various scripts and realised there is some kind of mistake in my code, as when I include these functions inside the same script area as my working drop down functions, the whole form breaks.

Here is the script containing the cookie methods:

***JAVASCRIPT***

```
function persist() {
    removeAllCookies();
    var fValues[] = new Array();
    var expiry = new Date(today.getTime() + 3600 * 1000); // 1 hour expiry 
    fValues[0] = document.getElementByName('calcType').value;
    fValues[1] = form.action.value;
    fValues[2] = document.getElementByName('transform').value;
    fValues[3] = document.getElementByName('calcResponse').value;
    fValues[4] = document.getElementByName('source').value;
    fValues[5] = document.getElementById('area').value;
    var i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
        element = fValues[i];
        writeCookie(i, element, expiry);
    }
}

function fillFromCookies() {
    var a = getCookie("0");
    var b = getCookie("1");
    var c = getCookie("2");
    var d = getCookie("3");
    var e = getCookie("4");
    var f = getCookie("5");
    if (b != null && f != null) {
        document.getElementByName('calcType').value = a;
        form.action.value = b;
        document.getElementByName('transform').value = c;
        document.getElementByName('calcResponse').value = d;
        document.getElementByName('source').value = e;
        document.getElementById('area').value = f;
    }
}

function writeCookie(id, value, expiry) {
    cookievalue = (value + ";");
    document.cookie = id + "=" + cookievalue + "; path=/; expires=" + expiry.toGMTString();
}

function getCookie(c_name) {
    if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
        c_start = document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=");
        if (c_start != -1) {
            c_start = c_start + c_name.length + 1;
            c_end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", c_start);
            if (c_end == -1) c_end = document.cookie.length;
            return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start, c_end));
        }
    }
    return "";
}

function deleteCookie(name) {
    var expired = new Date(today.getTime() - 24 * 3600 * 1000); 
    document.cookie = name + "=null; path=/; expires=" + expired.toGMTString();
}

function removeAllCookies() {
    deleteCookie("0");
    deleteCookie("1");
    deleteCookie("2");
    deleteCookie("3");
    deleteCookie("4");
    deleteCookie("5");
}
```

***HTML*** *(for test purposes)*

```
    calcType<br/>
    <textarea name="calcType" cols="150" rows="2">-</textarea><br/><br/>
    transform<br/>
    <input type="text" name="transform" size="50" value="-"/><br/><br/>
    calcResponse<br/>
    <input type="text" name="calcResponse" size="50" value="-"/><br/><br/>
    source<br/>
    <input type="text" name="source" size="50" value="-"/><br/><br/>
    test<br/>
    <input type="text" name="test" size="50" value="test"/><br/><br/>
    environment         
        <select id="Environment">
            <option>Pick one</option>
            <option>TEST</option>
        </select><div>
    product
        <select id="Product">
            <option>Pick one</option>
            <option>TEST</option>
        </select><div>
    brand
        <select id="Brand">
            <option>Choose Product First</option>
            <option>TEST</option>
        </select>
    <textarea id = "area" onload = "fillFromCookies();" name="calcData" cols="150" rows="50">
```

I call the persist() function like: `<form ..onsubmit="persist()"...>`

I call fillFromCookies() on the text area (containing the txt from the selected file) 
`textarea ..onload="fillFromCookies();"` property. (it is the last element in the HTML code).

I am relatively new to javascript so any comments on code are welcome and appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what your requirements are but my recommendation would be to use ajax to post the form to a server, that way your form is preserved because there is no post/call back to deal with.  You call another page that will then return your xml, which I believe you can parse with JQuery though if you are restricted to javascript you could still do it but it will be a little more involved.

```
$.ajax({url : url, dataType: "xml", success : function(data) { }, 
    error : function(request, status, error) { }
});
```

If posting the page is really important for whatever reason, then you can populate the form using dynamic html before it is sent to the client, depending on what server-side technology you are using how to do this will vary. Unfortunately, I can't help you with that without knowing more.

Finally here is a tutorial on setting cookies in javascript.  Hope this helps:
http://sicanstudios.com/post/set-cookies-javascript/

Comment: OK thank you for your comment. I have not used ajax before and I am not able to gain access to save a page onto a web server. This webpage will be loaded as a HTML page saved onto a local machine, and not part of a website. This is why I was looking at using cookies as a type of local storage while the user is testing various xml requests and responses.

Comment: Sorry about that a.hrdie.  I've edited my answer to include a link for a tutorial on using cookies but it uses Jquery.  I found that helpful but I'm afraid I've never done that sort of thing in pure javascript as Jquery makes it much easier.  If you are comfortable with Jquery that would be a good place to start.

Comment: Thank you, Jquery makes this look much easier! Will post completed code soon.

Comment: No problem, look forward to seeing it.

Answer (score 0):

I have been working at using cookies all day, and even looked into using AJAX to return the response to a separate text box. After a lot of research I found a really handy way to keep the form intact in order to compare the response and the input : open the response in a seperate tab.

By adding `target="_blank"` into the form tag, the XML returned by the sever is now shown in a new tab. Cookies would have been one way, but I had a lot of problems (due to beginner's understanding) with pure Javascript and different JQuery plug-ins.